# How to set up Active Paypal Adaptive Payment IPN Notifications correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been having trouble setting up the IPN Notification on my app to get all the information
send back to my application. My payment is working properly and is functional. I am having trouble with the notify_action. I would like to retrieve the information of the payment and send it back to my app to get all the informations from the payment.

```
 def checkout
  ....
  response = @gateway.setup_purchase(
     :return_url => "http://localhost:3000",
     :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000",
     :ipn_notification_url => orders_notify_action_url,
     :receiver_list => recipients
     )
  ..
  redirect_to (@gateway.redirect_url_for(response["payKey"]))
 end

 def notify_action
     notify =  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::PaypalAdaptivePayment::Notification.new(request.raw_post)
    p "Notification object is #{notify}"
    if notify.acknowledge
      p "Transaction ID is #{notify.transaction_id}"
      p "Notification object is #{notify}"
      p "Notification status is #{notify.status}"
    end
    render :nothing => true
end
```

https://gist.github.com/8acceeee72fe12312c09

Answer (score 1):

It would help a lot if you specified what problem you're having. For example, is the problem that notify_action is not being hit by Paypal's IPN? Or is notify.acknowledge returning false?

For strictly IPN this is what my working controller looks like:

```
class PayController < ApplicationController
    include ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations   

    def paypal
        notify = Paypal::Notification.new(request.raw_post)
        logger.debug "Notification object is #{notify}"
        if notify.acknowledge
            logger.debug "Transaction ID is #{notify.transaction_id}"
            logger.debug "Notification object is #{notify}"
            logger.debug "Notification status is #{notify.status}"
        end        
        render :nothing => true
    end
end
```

Then the URL I gave to Paypal is www.yourwebsite.com/pay/paypal

Then simply match the route in route.rb

```
match 'pay/paypal' => 'pay#paypal'
```

The notify object should contain all the data for the given purchase.

Important: Watch the log file to see if the function is ever getting called, and if so, what is being printed?